# Side nav menu on iOS app?

Tags: ios, menu, app

is it ok to put the side nav menu on application for the iOS?
Because I can't find it on iOS guideline design.

Comment: Just because it isn't in the guidelines doesn't mean it can't/shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 0):

It's not in the guidelines, but it's okay to include in your app -- various other apps (some examples [here](http://uxmag.com/articles/adapting-ui-to-ios-7-the-side-menu)) include it too.

That said, there are lots of articles that argue against hamburger buttons in general -- I'd recommend reading those. The general argument goes that you should be able to fit your main top-level navigation items in a tab bar, and if you can't, maybe your app is trying to do too much at once.

Comment: Tnx :)  I read already those articles and AB testing aproved that hamburger button was less clickable than menu one.

Answer (score 0):

No, at least not if you want to listen to apple.
See my answer on this question: [Is it OK to use hamburger menus in iOS?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/88000/67657)